# Angular app fails to load routes conditionally when the route has child module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need a way to build the application with or without 'comments' enabled. So I think I can use the environment variable.

```
import { environment } from 'app/../environments/environment';

let routes： Routes = [
    { path: 'jobs', component: JobsComponent}
];

if(environment.enable_comments) {
    // routes only for for the second app
    routes.push(
        { path: 'jobs/comments', loadChildren: 'app/comments/comments.module#CommentsModule'}
    );
}
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

Weirdly, it sometimes works, sometimes not. It only fails at this route  `jobs/comments`

> core.js:15714 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find
>   module  ...

Strangely, when I remove the conditions. I works just fine.

```
const routes： Routes = [
    { path: 'jobs', component: JobsComponent},
    { path: 'jobs/comments', loadChildren: 'app/comments/comments.module#CommentsModule'}
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

I am baffled here.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the Angular's built-in resolver - canLoad? - It does exactly what you are trying to accomplish out of the box. Check it out here > https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad

Comment: Not only loading children. I need to be able to remove any route based on what the app is - so it's kind of a slightly different build with different route-set. Basically if I hide the UI, I want to disable the routes related as well. So I can just change some variable, then build it to have another slightly different version of the app installed for someone else

Comment: I still can't see why you wouldn't do that with CanLoad. If the user is blocked from going to Route A, whether the route DNE, or CanLoad blocking it, it should provide you the same outcome.